# Which sentence is better?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I am trying to decide if I should use the phrase "have a strong" or "am familiar" in the following sentence.

> - In addition to web development skills, I *have a strong* familiarity with learning management systems.
> - In addition to web development skills, I *am familiar* with learning management systems.

Comment: *In addition to web development skills, I have a strong familiarity with learning management systems.* - does not make sense. In case the latter is a product/software, make the first letters capitals. Learning Management Systems.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences don't have flow. I think they lack in parallelism.

If in first part you are using *In addition to.... skills*, the later part better have something related/close to if not exactly the word *skills*.

Example:

> In addition to the twins, Jason has another child by his first wife. NOT 
>   In addition to the twins, Jason also teaches in the school!

Keep your sentence clear -

> I'm skilled in web development. Besides, I'm also familiar with Learning Management Systems.

Note: I guess that *learning* is a noun here and not a verb.

Comment: +1 Exactly. The introductory phrase/clause must serve the same syntactic role as the phrase/clause it parallels. Both *skills* and *familiarity* work as objects of *I have*, but *skills* does **not** work like *familiar* as a complement of *I am*.

Answer (score 0):

By taking out the word `have` you're also taking out the word `strong`.

This diminishes just *how* familiar you are with learning management systems.

To fix this you could say:

> In addition to web development skills, I am also very familiar with learning management systems.